# how to get current tabId from background page

Tags: google-chrome-extension

how to get current tabId from background page?
current tabId is the tab that user can see its content.

background.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>

    if(typeof localStorage.state == 'undefined')
        localStorage.state = 'off'
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
        if(localStorage.state == 'on')
        {
            localStorage.state = 'off';
        }
        else
        {
            localStorage.state = 'on';
        }
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: localStorage.state, tabId: tab.id});
        chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {state: localStorage.state});
        //chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {state: localStorage.state});
    });
    </script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 55):

`getSelected` has been [deprecated](https://developer.chrome.com/dev/extensions/whats_new.html#16). The new way to do it is:

```js
chrome.tabs.query(
  {currentWindow: true, active : true},
  function(tabArray){...}
)
```

If you want to perform some callback on the active tab, you can wrap the above as so:

```js
function doInCurrentTab(tabCallback) {
    chrome.tabs.query(
        { currentWindow: true, active: true },
        function (tabArray) { tabCallback(tabArray[0]); }
    );
}
```

For example

```js
var activeTabId;
doInCurrentTab( function(tab){ activeTabId = tab.id } );
```

Comment: @neaumusic I have a problem with your edit. It changes a bit too much of the author's code and contains false information (`tabArray[0]` is not an ID). I'm rolling this back.

Comment: @neaumusic That said, you can definitely post your code as an answer.

Comment: This totally does not seem to work any more. If I do a `console.log(activeTabId);` from within the callback (e.g. `function(tab){ ... }`) I can see that tab.id is set, but then as soon as doInCurrentTab returns, activeTabId remains undefined. Did Google change something that broke this?

Answer (score 10):

Run this in your background page

```
chrome.tabs.query({active:true,windowType:"normal", currentWindow: true},function(d){console.debug(d);})
```

or even better

```
chrome.tabs.query({active:true,windowType:"normal", currentWindow: true},function(d){console.debug(d[0].id);})
```

Comment: This will get all active tabs in all windows. So if you have more than one window open you'll get several tabs back.

Comment: For the onlookers - it was edited with `currentWindow` to solve Soviut's issue.

Comment: Note that just running this code in a background page's devtools window won't return anything. If you run it in a timeout and then switch to regular window, you'll see it return the active tab: `setTimeout(() => chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, console.log), 2000)`

Answer (score 6):

According to the official documentation: Manifest V3 (promise), which will be enforced since Jan 2023
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#get-the-current-tab

```
async function getCurrentTab() {
  let queryOptions = { active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true };
  let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query(queryOptions);
  return tab;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Many API methods interpret `null` as a current tab. `chrome.tabs.sendRequest` is one of them.

Otherwise:

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) { ... })
```

Comment: Should now use query instead: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-getSelected

Answer (score 2):

If you have `tabs` user permission, the query method is this: [chrome.tabs.query](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query)

---

```
getCurrentWindowActiveTabIndex().then(tabIndex => {
    // do something
});

// asnyc getter, not just a regular 'thunk'
function getCurrentWindowActiveTabIndex () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        chrome.tabs.query({
            currentWindow: true,
            active: true,
        }, (currentWindowActiveTabs = []) => {
            if (!currentWindowActiveTabs.length) reject();
            resolve(currentWindowActiveTabs[0].index);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: A little bit of explanation of what this code does, and why is this answer better than others, would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

For manifest version 3
Here :

```
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs){
  console.log(tabs[0].url);
  my_tabid=tabs[0].id;
  alert(my_tabid);
});
//then use it, my_tabid
```