# popup.js is not being executed within head tag at popup.html in chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This may sound silly but I really can't figure it out.
[At this link](https://gist.github.com/greatghoul/8120275), [greatghoul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/260793/greatghoul) has written a nice script.

But this only works when `<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>` is used within body tag. But if I use this code in head tag. It doesn't work.

I want to understand why. And How I can use jquery in popup.html? Basically I was trying to use [datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) in popup.html.

there is another [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764517/execute-script-after-click-in-popup-html-chrome-extension).

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put this into `<head>`, it will execute before `#clickme` exists in the DOM.

Solution is to wrap your code in a `DOMContentLoaded` listener:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.getElementById('clickme').addEventListener('click', hello);
});
```