# Why is window.open() and window.close() not working in Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Alright so I'm currently in the process of trying to automate some tasks via a chrome extension. Here are all my files, the issue is with my content.js:

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Click to execute",
  "description": "Execute script after click in popup.html (chrome extension) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764517/execute-script-after-click-in-popup-html-chrome-extension.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "icons": {
    "48": "icon.png"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "<all_urls>"
  ],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

popup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body style="width: 300px">
    Open <a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">this page</a> and then 
    <button id="clickme">click me</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js:

```
function hello() {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    file: 'content.js'
  }); 
}

document.getElementById('clickme').addEventListener('click', hello);
```

content.js:

```
let firstCl = function(){
document.getElementsByClassName('nav-link')[6].click();
};

let openWin = function(){
    window.open('www.google.com');
};

let closeWin = function(){
    window.close()
}


setTimeout(firstCl, 3000);
setTimeout(openWin, 6000);
setTimeout(closeWin, 9000);
```

Im trying to click on a link, then open a new tab with google.com, then wait a while and close that tab automatically. For some reason the window.close(); method inst doing anything, google opens and then just stays open. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So two things I see that will help you out.

1. If you want a new tab to open you will need to do add `'_blank'` otherwise it will just take over the current window. so `window.open('www.google.com', '_blank');`
2. You need to reference the window you opened. So assign it to a variable and then close that specific window that was spawned

```js
let theWindow;

let firstCl = function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('nav-link')[6].click();
};

let openWin = function() {
  theWindow = window.open('www.google.com', '_blank');
};

let closeWin = function() {
  theWindow.close()
}

setTimeout(firstCl, 3000);
setTimeout(openWin, 6000);
setTimeout(closeWin, 9000);
```