# executeScript is undefined or not a function in a ManifestV3 extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Why is this function from Chrome not working? I'm trying this example:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#programmatic.

I'm developing an extension for chrome and sending a message from **popup.js** to service worker **background.js** and get error in `executeScript`.

### popup.js

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ from: "newScript"});
```

### manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "TennisBet",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Extrension for bet on tennis.",
    "action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "256": "images/tennis256.png",
            "128": "images/tennis128.png",
            "64": "images/tennis64.png",
            "32": "images/tennis32.png",
            "24": "images/tennis24.png",
            "16": "images/tennis16.png"
        },
        "default_popup": "popup/popup.html"
    },
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background-wrapper.js"
    },
    "host_permissions": ["*://*/*"],
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "alarms",
        "activeTab",
        "declarativeContent",
        "storage"
    ]
}
```

### background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    switch(request.from){
        case "error":
            console.log(request.message);
            break;
        case "checkTabs":
            tabsWorker();      
            break;
        case "newScript":
            chrome.scripting.executeScript({ // Error in event handler: TypeError: Cannot read property 'executeScript' of undefined
                file: "content_scripts/cscript.js"
            });
            break;
        default:
            console.log("Message listener status active");
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: The link you gave says `chrome.scripting` not `chrome.tabs`.

Comment: @wOxxOm The thing is, I've tried and "chrome.scripting.executeScript" and get error:
"Error in event handler: TypeError: Unable to read executeScript property of undefined value"
Now i editing this post

Comment: Well, it's a separate API so it needs `"scripting"` in `"permissions"` in manifest.json.You can report the bug in this documentation, there's a link at the bottom.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The `executeScript` method in ManifestV3 has changed and is now in `chrome.scripting` API:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/

Add this line in manifest.json:

```
"permissions": ["scripting"]
```

background.js

```
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: {tabId: id, allFrames: true},
    files: ['content_scripts/cscript.js'],
});
```

Comment: In case it didn't jump out at you, notice that `tabId` is now part of the passed object and not an argument. Also, the passed object is [`ScriptInjection`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#type-ScriptInjection) rather than [`InjectDetails`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/extensionTypes/#type-InjectDetails). I haven't compared the objects to see if there are other differences, but it's worth keeping your eyes open.

Comment: And also, if you're using manifestV3, you  need to set `"background": {
    "service_worker": "workers/background.js", <--- your background worker file path
    "type": "module"
  },` on `manifest.json` like that.