# How to get a Chrome tab's ID in Selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I know that you can get browser process ID in Selenium (`driver.service.process.id`), but is it possible to get the IDs of the tabs?

I read through the documentation, but it does not say how you can get the IDs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303452/how-to-get-current-tabid-from-background-page may help